# Contar el numero de 5.0 desde el inicio de una Lista-Ligada

Tags: java, funciones, lista

Intento resolver una función que retorna la posición de los primero '5.0' desde el inicio en una LinkedList. Debo retornar un numero negativo si la lista esta vacía o si el primer elemento de la lista no es un '5.0'.

La función pasa los test cuando encuentra los primeros '5.0' pero falla cuando el primer item de la lista no es un '5.0'. 
Quisiera saber si hay un error en la lógica de mi función o si es la manera en que los tests están escritos?
Cualquier pista en que anda mal es una gran ayuda, gracias!

**La función devuelve la posición de los primero '5.0' desde el inicio:**

```
    public int positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(){
    int result = 0;
    if(first == null){
        return -1;
    }
    Node x = first;
    while(x != null){
        if(x.item == 5.0){
            return result;
        }
        result++;
        x = x.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

> Failed [ 11 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting [-1]
>   Actual [1]
>
> Failed [ 11 21 31 41 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting
>   [-1] Actual [4]
>
> Finished tests

**Función falla todos los tests cuando la modifico para contar el item que no es un '5.0':**

```
    public int positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(){
    int result = 0;
    if(first == null || first.item != 5.0){
        return -1;
    }
        Node x = first;
        while (x != null) {
            if (x.item == 5.0) {
                return result;
            }
            result++;
            x = x.next;
        }
    return result;
}
```

> Failed [ 11 5 21 31 41 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting
>   [1] Actual [-1]
>
> Failed [ 11 21 5 31 41 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting
>   [2] Actual [-1]
>
> Failed [ 11 21 31 5 41 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting
>   [3] Actual [-1]
>
> Failed [ 11 21 31 41 5 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(): Expecting
>   [4] Actual [-1]
>
> Failed [ 0 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 8 9 ].positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning():
>   Expecting [3] Actual [-1]
>
> Finished tests

Comment: x es un objeto tipo Node, no se si puedas preguntarte si es null.

Comment: Disculpa pero eso no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que tienes la referencia a first nula, por eso siempre devuelve -1

Comment: intenta x = x.intem despues del result++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo pensaría que lo mejor sería dejarlo como el primero modificandole el último **Return**, osea:

```
public int positionOfFirstFiveFromBeginning(){
int result = 0;
if(first == null){
    return -1;
}
Node x = first;
while(x != null){
    if(x.item == 5.0){
        return result;
    }
    result++;
    x = x.next;
}
return -1; //en vez de "result" 
}
```

Espero que sea de ayuda!

Comment: Perfecto! Paso todos tests. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías marcar mi respuesta como la correcta, gracias!